# row in generation in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I want to transfer data of table A,column emp_name to Table B with column name EMP_NAME.

I want that EMP_ID column of Table B to be equal to row_id.How this can be done in sql

or ssis..?

Comment: What does "row_id" mean here? What is it and where does the value come from?

Comment: Row number of what? Rows in tables don't have row numbers, so do you want to add one when you copy the data and if so, what is the logic for generating this number?

Answer (score 0):

what have you tried?

You will need two connections, one for each DB and one data flow component which will have a OleDBSource and an OleDBDestination component inside.

On the OleDBSource you can select your connection and write your query and then you drag the green arrow to the OleDBDestination. Double click the OleDBDestination select destination connection and table and click on mapping.

Should be it

SQL:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY emp_name DESC) AS 'emp_id on table B', emp_name
FROM table
```

Comment: Problem is in writing the query..not in approach

Comment: you didn't give enough information, but see if my query helps

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO
TableB (EMP_ID, EMP_NAME)

SELECT
A.row_id
A.emp_name

FROM

TableA AS A
```

but for this to work EMP_ID on TableB must not be defined as an IDENTITY column (assuming you are in SQL Server).